# How to create record for Phonecall Activity in Dynamics CRM 365 for 'CallFrom' and 'CallTo'

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

```
`if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phonecall.From))
phonecallEntity.Attributes.Add("from", new EntityReference("systemuser", new 
Guid(phonecall.From)));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phonecall.To))
phonecallEntity.Attributes.Add("to", new EntityReference("contact", new 
Guid(phonecall.To)));
```

I'm trying to set the from and to field on a Phone Call activity in Dynamics 365. I'm using the following code but the to and from fields are empty when creating a Phone Call. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to` and `from` fields on `Activity` entities (line Phone Call) expect an `EntityCollection`, not an `EntityReference` as you are trying to pass them.

Each entity within your `EntityCollection` should be an `ActivityParty` linked to an `EntityReference`:

```cs
// Create your collection.
var collection = new EntityCollection();

// Create your parties; one party per reference (to/from).
var party1 = new Entity("activityparty");
party["partyid"] = new EntityReference(logicalName, id);


// Add your parties to your collection.
collection.Entities.Add(party1);

// Set your to phone call's to field.
phoneCallEntity["to"] = collection;
```